# Grunt prepend all links and paths

Tags: gruntjs

I've recently started using Grunt for an AngularJS based webshop, and it's been working absolutely great! During the development of the project, I've been working on my local machine, developing using Grunts own server. Now we are in the stage of deploying the project, but run into a couple of hickups.

Since our webshop will be used as a WordPress theme, all paths need to be prepended with `/wp-content/themes/ourtheme/`. That is, all local resources (including assets in LESS-files), that need to have this absolute path specified.

What would be the best way to do this? If it is to any help, I created the project using the Yeoman Angular generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `grunt` task [grunt-string-replace](https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace) to find and replace all the matching patterns, for example:

```
'string-replace': {
  inline: {
    files: {
      'dest/': 'src/**',
    },
    options: {
      replacements: [
        // place files inline example
        {
          pattern: 'your/relative/path/',
          replacement: 'wp-content/themes/ourtheme/your/relative/path'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I feel like there should be abetter solution to solve this, this will do it for now :) Thank you!